# Convert Promise<any> to specific type error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

Newbie question with typescript/angular4+/ionic4. I have a service implemented which would make the backend REST Call and based on the response of the call I would store that information obtained into the local Storage. 
The reason why that is in local storage so that I can query the same at a later point in time. I seem to be getting the type conversion error. Any leads would help.

```
 this.locationService.saveLocationNew(this.newLocation).subscribe(res=> {
     this.locationInfo = res;
     console.log('Response from backend'+ this.locationInfo);
     this.storage.set(StorageKeys.LOCATION_DATA, this.locationInfo);
     this.locationInfo = null;
     this.locationInfo = <AddLocationResponse>this.storage.get(StorageKeys.LOCATION_DATA); --> this is where I see the type conversion error.
   });
```

My service looks like this

```
 saveLocationNew(request: AddLocationData): Observable<AddLocationResponse> {
      return this.httpClient.post<AddLocationResponse>(this.addLocationUrl, request , { headers: Constants.createHeader()}); --> I don't use a then and map res to res.json ; since that is not needed in Ionic4
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 this.locationService.saveLocationNew(this.newLocation).subscribe(async (res)=> {
     this.locationInfo = res;
     console.log('Response from backend'+ this.locationInfo);
     this.storage.set(StorageKeys.LOCATION_DATA, this.locationInfo);
     this.locationInfo = null;
     const res = await <AddLocationResponse>this.storage.get(StorageKeys.LOCATION_DATA).catch((err) => 'return anything you want');
     if (res) {
       this.locationInfo = res;
     }
   });
```

Comment: I see this error : Conversion of type 'Promise<any>' to type 'AddLocationResponse' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Comment: This seems to be working for me but this is async :  this.storage.get (StorageKeys.LOCATION_DATA).then( (val)=> {
               this.locationData = val;
             }
             );

Comment: Any way to make this call from Async to Sync ?

Comment: I realised it would be better to place all of these calls in the ionViewLoad() so that some of the local storage queries which I need to make would be available much earlier on

Answer (score 0):

Check for type with TypeError

```
function determineIfIsAnimalOrHuman(toBeDetermined: PersonOrAnimal): toBeDetermined is Animal {
  if((toBeDetermined as Animal).type){
    // do some thing
  }
   throw new TypeError('Object is no Animal');
}
```